# Multiplying two RDD in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new to pyspark. I have been trying to multiply two sparse RDD. The code whichI have tried generates two sparse matrices and I have written a function to multiply the two RDD but I think this is not the solution as the computations does not occur in parallel. Can someone help me with it? How can I multiply the RDD in parallel? I tried out a lot of resources on the sites but could not come up with a solution.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import numpy as np
import pyspark
import random
from scipy.sparse import rand
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="matrix")

np.random.seed(42)
n=4
x = rand(n, n, density=0.25)
y = rand(n, n, density=0.25)
A = x.A
B = y.A
rdd_x = sc.parallelize(A)
rdd_y = sc.parallelize(B)
def multiply(r1, r2):
   A = r1.collect()
   B = r2.collect()
   result = []
   for i in range(len(B[0])): 
       total = 0
       for j in range(len(A)): 
           total += A[j] * B[j][i]
       result.append(total)
   return result
C = multiply(rdd_x,rdd_x)
print(C)
sc.stop()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `collect()` anyway, you might as well use [np.multiply()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html):

```
C = np.multiply(np.array(rdd_x.collect()), np.array(rdd_y.collect()))
```

Or if you want a dot product, you can use [np.dot()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

```
C = np.dot(np.array(rdd_x.collect()), np.array(rdd_y.collect()))
```

Comment: `"Usually, collect() is used to retrieve the action output when you have very small result set and calling collect() on an RDD/DataFrame with a bigger result set causes out of memory"`... In my case, trying to implement Page Rank with iterative multiplications would be nonsense. It's obvious this is not right right way to do things.